# RefreshIndicator not working with Scrollview

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to use RefreshIndicator with Scrollview as want extra widgits too with list in RefreshIndicator but it is not working.

Basically I want to use RefreshIndicator then inside it a Scrollview with a column with multiple widgets.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  List<String> _demoData = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    _demoData = [
      "Flutter",
      "React Native",
      "Cordova/ PhoneGap",
      "Native Script"
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future doRefresh() {
      return Future.delayed(
        Duration(seconds: 0),
        () {
          setState(() {
            print("refresh worked");
            _demoData.addAll(["Ionic", "Xamarin"]);
          });
        },
      );
    }

    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: doRefresh,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,         
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 400,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(_demoData[idx]),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: _demoData.length,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your list that has the 'RefreshIndicator' is in another list, this only scrolls the parent list and the child list where the 'RefreshIndicator' is located will not work, delete the parent list and have it only display the child list like the following example:

- Another problem is also that the 'doRefresh' method is inside the 'build' method of the Widget, take it out of the 'build' method like the example: (in seconds put 2 or 3 seconds to see the animation)

```dart
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  List<String> _demoData = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    _demoData = [
      "Flutter",
      "React Native",
      "Cordova/ PhoneGap",
      "Native Script"
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  Future doRefresh() {
    return Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 3),
      () {
        setState(() {
          print("refresh worked");
          _demoData.addAll(["Ionic", "Xamarin"]);
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: doRefresh,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) {
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(_demoData[idx]),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: _demoData.length,
        ));
  }
}
```

If you want to add more widgets, those widgets have to be inside the ListView, if you want to use more lists it is better to use a [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) instead of the ListView

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: doRefresh,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ...List.generate(
                _demoData.length,
                (idx) => Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(_demoData[idx]),
                      ),
                    )),
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            ...List.generate(
                _demoData.length,
                (idx) => Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(_demoData[idx]),
                      ),
                    )),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Yes it is working but now how can I add more widgets inside RefreshIndicator as I want to add multiple widgets inside RefreshIndicator